# java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null a kotlin error

Tags: android, kotlin

I have kotlin/java project connected to firebase and in firebase crashlytics its showing the below log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter token
       at network.TokenManagerImpl.saveToken(:2)
       at data.user.UserRepositoryImpl$login$2.invokeSuspend(UserRepository.kt:37)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

i think here is the code line mentioned in the log and by default its passing as null but i cant remove it, if i do so then red error would show to that line.

```
init { sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USER_TOKEN, null)?.let { saveToken(it) } }
```

i tried making removing the defValue as null but it gave error on that line.

Comment: If the default value of `getString` may not be `null`, you have to pass a value *other than `null`*.

Comment: @ThomasBehr it should not be an issue, because he uses `?.let {}` So, the let operation should only execute if `it` is not null. Are we sure that saveToken is only called by init ? because the stack-trace indicate a suspending call, and I am not sure init fits that.